# SSIS Foreach File Enumerator finds no files when executed from deployed package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've seen this question asked several times but never with a satisfacory answer. I have read through all the posts I can related to this and tried as much as I possibly can.

I have an SSIS package that loops thru a network folder of Excel files, I won't explain what it does inseide the loop container as that is not relevant.

I refernce the folder via a UNC \servername\folder

1. The package works fine from within Visual Studio.
2. I deployed the package to the Integration Services Catalogs on the
   server
3. After I deploy, I connect to the server from my local pc via SSMS and then I execute it from SSMS via "Integration Services Catalogs"... Execute  - This fails.
4. **However** If I remote desktop onto the SQL Server box, then start SSMS, connect to the SQL Server using my own credentials and execute the package using exactly the same method as above it works fine.

When I look in the logs of the failed attempts I see a warning that "The For Each File enumerator is empty". I'm not sure if this is telling the full story as, if I rename the network folder, I get the same message, (I expected to see an error that the folder was not found) - this may or may not be relevant.

I've sketched up a quick overview of what works and what doesn't

**NOTE** *The "script execution" method is just a t-sql script for running these packages. This is the method I will use eventually but at the moment I'm focusing on the simple right-click execute method as this essentially does the same thing.*

[image]

Since I did this I have tried a few more things...

- I've tried accessing the folder as a UNC, a mapped drive and also UNC using IP address instead of server name.
- I recreated the issue on our development server so I could change
  service accounts etc.
- I tried the default accounts on both SSIS and SQL Agent services.
- I tried changing these to domain accounts and network service accounts.

I get the package to log the folder name which is and expression - this always looks correct. I do the same with the user name which always shows me as the exection user.

I can change most things as I can test on the development server with the excpetion of testing with a domain admin account so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that this is a double hop issue, and so you are attempting to authenticate to the directory as an anonymous user; and hence there are no files. *Note, Executing a script to run the package, and right clicking the package in SSISDB and running are effectively the same; the latter uses a GUI to generate a script that it then executes. The same way as if you were to create a `LOGIN` via the `GUI`, or alter the permissions on an object.*

Comment: Thanks for the response @Larnu. My network knowledge is not that great so I'm not sure how I can resolve it if it is the double-hop issue. I'm going to try one or two more things in the meantime. BTW: The script I mentioned does replicate the SSMS method in that it generates an executionid using `[catalog].[create_execution]` and then executes it using `[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id`. This bit works fine for other packages so I'm not worried about this at the moment.

Comment: It's not my expertise either, I'm afraid, Alan. Ensuring that "double hopping" was allowed (via kerboros) was something our Network Administrator set up, and I "believe" it's set at host level, not domain (though I could be very wrong on that, as it could be that's the route that chose to take for our environment).

Comment: If I don;t get anywhere I'll speak to IT and see if that makes sense to them. If I do resolve it I'll post back here, thanks again.

Comment: Seconding Larnu's insight. Smells very strongly of kerberos double hop issue. MS article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/ba-p/395463  House of Brick article https://houseofbrick.com/microsoft-made-an-easy-button-for-spn-and-double-hop-issues/

Comment: thanks @billinkc I'll  read the articles and see where I get (or pass them to IT ! ) I think you both might be correct though as I changed the package to use a local disk on the SQL server (via a UNC) and it works fine in all instances. Not a production solution but narrows down the search a bit.